# GET Facebook wall posts of admin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

What started off as easy as "Let's put all our brand's Facebook posts on our website" has turned out much more difficult.

**The situation:**

1. There are multiple admins that manage the Facebook fan page (20+)
2. RSS feeds no longer seem to work with some brand pages
3. I have registered an APP ID, and am getting back an access token at an application level like so:

   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=AAAAAAAA&client_secret=BBBBBBBB;

Below are some varying cases and what they return. All examples below assume the access token is retrieved using the URL above

**Case 1: /posts**

Will return the wall posts of the parent account (the one who started the Facebook fan page), and not the admin's who administer it.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/posts?access_token=XXXXXXXXXX;
```

**Case 2: /feed**

Will return the wall posts by all other users, and NOT the admins or page owners

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/feed?access_token=XXXXXXXXXX;
```

**Case 3: FQL**

Will return same results as Case 1, note DDDDDDD = Page UID

```
SELECT post_id, created_time, message FROM stream WHERE source_id=DDDDDDDD AND actor_id=DDDDDDDD
```

Now, funnily enough, when I use Facebook's Graph API Explorer (logged in of course), and I call Case 1 above "/posts" I DO get all the posts (including the ones from all page admins and owners). This is exactly what I want!

So why am I here? Because of the access token issue. This is a stream to be used on a website, i.e. there is no requirement for a user to connect to Facebook as we don't need their permissions nor to access their data, which is why I'm using the application access token.

Answer (score 1):

Is manage_pages permission given to your app token? I hope this link helps: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this still requires a user to authenticate, and I'm struggling to find a way to just let the code do it's work. Once more, I don't need the user's permission, because I'm not accessing their data. I'm accessing the data of a public brand fan page, which is why it's confusing me.